# Java text field for credit card number only showing last 4 digits

Tags: java, swing

I have to do a supermarket app in Java for a class, one of the many requirements is that when a purchase is being made it asks for the credit/debit card data, and when the user fills the credit card number field it only displays the last four digits, something like XXXXXXXXXXXX1456

I am using Java Swing for the GUI and I have tried to use the formatted field, the password field and a normal field and I can´t seem to find a way to make it only display the last four digits when is being filled.

Comment: "Format" the text BEFORE you apply it to the field, I'd start with the prefix you want to use a `static String`, get the last 4 characters from the text and simple combine them together

Comment: I'm not sure that makes sense (to me).  Why would you mask the input in such away?  How would the user possibly verify what they've input.  I get masking it as output, but input seems .... weird

Comment: please describe the _exact_ behaviour you want to achieve: simple masking after input might require a different approach that masking during input.

Comment: @MadProgrammer while I - as a user - hate a ux that doesn't show my input, there are examples f.i. in mobile and/or browser contexts where only the currently typed char is shown and then is (animatedly, OMG ;) is hidden, the more user-friendly variants having an eye picture that re-shows the input when clicked.

Comment: @kleopatra I don't know what you've been buying, but I've never seen it - I "might" consider a on focus lost state, but not while the user is typing

Comment: @MadProgrammer don't know what you mean by _buying_ (all my apps are free, neither stolen nor bought <g>) but you are right: I should come up with an example .. will do next time I stumble across it (my memory isn't as crisp as it used to be ;)

Answer (score 1):

A [`JFormattedTextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) has a *formatter factory*. I looked at the code of the default *formatter factory* – which is class `DefaultFormatterFactory` – and tried to adapt it to your requirements.

That class defines several *formatter* classes: one for when the `JFormattedTextField` is in *edit* mode, i.e. it has the keyboard focus and another for *display* mode, i.e. when the `JFormattedTextField` does **not** have keyboard focus.

In the below code I created a `CreditCardFormatterFactory` class as well as a `CreditCardEditFormatter` class and a `CreditCardDisplayFormatter` class.

Note that I may have misunderstood your requirements, so the below code may not be exactly what you require but I would like to think that it is good enough for you to be able to adapt it to your exact requirements.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FtfTest {
    private void buildAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createFormattedTextField(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createButton(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createFormattedTextField() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Credit Card Number");
        panel.add(label);
        JFormattedTextField creditCardFormattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField(
                                                                 new CreditCardFormatterFactory());
        creditCardFormattedTextField.setColumns(16);
        panel.add(creditCardFormattedTextField);
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButton() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Exit");
        button.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));
        panel.add(button);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new FtfTest().buildAndDisplayGui());
    }
}

class CreditCardFormatterFactory extends JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatterFactory {

    /** {@code JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter} to use for display. */
    private JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter displayFormat;

    /** {@code JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter} to use for editing. */
    private JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter editFormat;

    /** {@code JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter} to use if the value is null. */
    private JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter nullFormat;

    public CreditCardFormatterFactory() {
        displayFormat = new CreditCardDisplayFormatter();
        editFormat = new CreditCardEditFormatter();
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractFormatter getFormatter(JFormattedTextField ftf) {
        JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter format = null;
        if (ftf != null) {
            if (ftf.hasFocus()) {
                format = getEditFormatter();
            }
            else {
                format = getDisplayFormatter();
            }
        }
        return format;
    }

    public JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter getDisplayFormatter() {
        return displayFormat;
    }

    public JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter getEditFormatter() {
        return editFormat;
    }

    public JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter getNullFormatter() {
        return nullFormat;
    }
}

class CreditCardDisplayFormatter extends JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter {

    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
        System.out.printf("CreditCardDisplayFormatter.stringToValue( ^%s^ )%n", text);
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
        System.out.printf("CreditCardDisplayFormatter.valueToString( ^%s^ )%n",
                          String.valueOf(value));
        String str = value == null ? "" : value.toString();
        if (str.length() > 0) {
            if (str.length() > 12) {
                str = "XXXXXXXXXXXX" + str.substring(12);
            }
            else {
                str = str.replaceAll("\\d", "X");
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
}

class CreditCardEditFormatter extends JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter {

    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
        System.out.printf("CreditCardEditFormatter.stringToValue( ^%s^ )%n", text);
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
        System.out.printf("CreditCardEditFormatter.valueToString( ^%s^ )%n",
                          String.valueOf(value));
        return value == null ? null : value.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String number = "6235761255231456";
String mask = number.replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d{4})", "X");
System.out.println(mask);

OutPut:
XXXXXXXXXXXX1456
```

here replace we are using replaceAll method which will take regular expression as parameter and and will replace every digit with X except last four digit the following regular expression is accepting all except last 4 digit.

Comment: please demonstrate how to apply that to the context of a textField